# How to trigger AJAX requst only onmouseover

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have below script which shows values from search page `onmouseover`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preview(val) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search.php",
        data:'id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $(".ress").html(data);
        }
    });
   }
 </script>
```

html :

```
<div class="CVSearchResult" onmouseover="preview('1')">
```

search :

```
<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>
```

output for class .ress :

```
1
```

However I want to hide the output `onmouseout` as well. How can I do this? I mean just trigger the AJAX for mouse hover and hide if not hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="CVSearchResult" onmouseover="preview('1')" onmouseout="hide()">
<script>
function hide() {
    $(".ress").html('');
} 
</script>
```

You are adding event handler when user move the mouse away from the element to trigger hide function.

The hude function grab the result dom element(which can contain selected results from previous calls) and set the html to empty string.

That way when you move away with the mouse the div element is cleared.

Comment: i think there is issue with this code. can you please re check your code?

Comment: I forgot the closing "'"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Well I made a little fiddle instead to show how you could do it.

[Fiddle with it](https://jsfiddle.net/jhk6uyvy/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="CVSearchResult" data-mydata="1">
  HOVER ON ME1
</div>
<div class="ress">
  This was hidden but is now visible.1
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".CVSearchResult").on("mouseover", function() {
    preview($(this).attr("data-mydata"));
  });
  $(".CVSearchResult").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".ress").css("display", "none");
  })
})
function preview(val) {
  $(".ress").css("border", "2px solid black");
    /* Add your own ajax call here to get the data that you want... */
  var data = val;
  $(".ress").html(data);
  $("div.ress").css("display", "block");
    /* --- */
}
```

CSS

```
.ress {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: now this is working, but after this i got one small issue. As the mouseover data is from ajax, each time if i move cursor over the class then date is reloading (blinks if cursor move).

Comment: You could move the ajax call to the document ready function so it runs when the page loads instead, then when you mouse over it the data is already loaded and things should be more static from there on out.
You would probably have to make a for-loop to go through all the search results if you have more than one. Something like:
    $('.CVSearchResults').each(function(key, value) {
        $.ajax(.....)
    });